# What is this plant? Broadleaf, bushy, narrower leaves

Tags: identification

southeast Michigan USA.  We weed-spray a right-of-way for basically everything.  The next spring, this little guy pretty much takes over the place (as everything else but bull thistle is still suppressed).

What is this?

(Disregard the viny one coming over from bottom right, its roots are well beyond the treated area).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's horseweed (*Conyza canadensis*), a really nasty bugger for airborne seeds. [Here](http://florafinder.com/Species/Conyza_canadensis.php) is more information. I generally pull it when I see it - at least it's an easy weed to hand-pull, especially when it's a foot tall or so and I don't have to bend down too far :)  Do not under any circumstances let it flower and go to seed, or you'll have even more seedlings to deal with next year.

Comment: Thanks.  It's invading an area we applied a full-spectrum herbicide to last year, and it's going wild because one of the only plants able to thrive in the residue. Fortunately, it really does not like 2,4-D, which is cheap.